# c++ for loop different way

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Recently, I round a beautiful way to output a vector from [std::partition_point](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition_point/).

```
  std::cout << "odd:";
  for (int& x:odd) std::cout << ' ' << x;
  std::cout << '\n';
```

Could anyone give a short description how it works and why it works? I would appreciate if someone could find this usage of for loop in documentation, unfortunately I didn't find it on http://www.cplusplus.com/.

Comment: See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a range-based loop of C++: you specify a loop variable and a container, and the compiler produces code that iterates the container, and assigns the loop variable each item of the container in turn before executing loop's body. This loop construct is not available prior to C++11.

Note that there is a way to output a container without using loops at all:

```
std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it (std::cout, " ");
std::copy( odd.begin(), odd.end(), out_it );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could be interested in boost::foreach implementation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/foreach.html. This is not exactly implemention of standard for loop, but you can debug and study foreach.hpp file. Below I append example that you could be interested in:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

int main()
{
   std::string hello( "Hello, world!" );

   BOOST_FOREACH( char ch, hello )
   {
     std::cout << ch;
   }

   return 0;
}
```